# Modify sheet names using variables of another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a sheet called "GRAPH" and two special cells (F4 and F5):

F4 = 2013
F5 = 2014

In my workbook there are sheets named: DATA jan 2013, DATA feb 2013, DATA mar 2013 etc

I want to replace "2013" by "2014" in all of them but I get the "Subscript out of range" error when I try to do the following:

> Sub test() 
>               Dim X1, X2 As Variant
>
> ```
>         'X1 is to old as X2 is to new value
>
>         X1 = Sheets("GRAPH").Range("F$4").Value
>         X2 = Sheets("GRAPH").Range("F$5").Value 
>
>        Sheets("DATA jan & X1").Select 
>         ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA jan & X2"
>              Sheets("DATA feb & X1").Select 
>              ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA feb & X2"
>                   Sheets("DATA mar & X1").Select 
>                   ActiveSheet.Name = "DATA mar & X2"
> ```

```
        End Sub
```

How to solve that?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I think it is just font. On my screen the O after Dim is virtually circular whereas the O used on the line O = ... is more oval shaped. Probably just my machine.

Comment: Replace `"DATA jan & X1"` by `"DATA jan " & X1`.  You have made `& X1` part of the literal rather than concatenation of a variable.  Repeat for all the other literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `"sheetname2 & O"` to `"sheetname2" & O`. Same with `N` on the next line.

Comment: @LuizVaughan I don't see the changes in the question w.r.t Jean-Francois' point. Have you noticed the specific point about the speech marks?

Comment: @Cor_Blimey I replaced O and N. Now X1 and X2 yields the same error. It should be a simple task but it is not working.

Comment: @LuizVaughan no, it is not that: look carefully at the difference between `Sheets("DATA jan & X1")` and `Sheets("DATA jan " & X1)`